# Disable checkbox on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 2 radio buttons and would like to disable checkboxes in an `array` if radio button is clicked. Here is some code from a previous post in `.net`.

I use `ASP` classic and would appreciate assistance in altering this code or code that would best accomplish my goal.

```
<input type="radio" name="group" value="value1">
<input type="radio" name="group" value="value2">

This is the checkbox that is in the loop for the array:

<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="<%=Rs("item") %>">


 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#<%= rbRadioButton.ClientID %> input').change(function () {
         // The one that fires the event is always the
         // checked one; you don't need to test for this
         alert($(this).val());
     });
 });
```

Comment: Please supply the HTML that goes with this code.

Comment: `array.forEach(el => el.disabled = true)`

Comment: @Tibrogargan html has been posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the `.prop()` method.

```js
// Disable checkbox
$("input[value='value1']").change(function() {
  $("input[name='items']").prop('disabled', true);
});

// Enable checkbox
$("input[value='value2']").change(function() {
  $("input[name='items']").prop('disabled', false);
});

// Trigger reset button click
$("#btnReset").on("click", function() {
  $("input[name='group']").prop('checked', false);
  $("input[name='items']").prop('checked', false);
  $("input[name='items']").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>radio:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="value1">disabled
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="value2">enabled
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>checkbox:</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="5">
</fieldset>

<input type="button" value="Reset" id="btnReset">
```

Comment: Nicely done, thank you. Is there a way, if the user changes mind to clear (other than the obvious refresh) to remove the checkbox disable to select the checkboxes?  Perhaps a clear button that doesn't refresh the page. Or if the user were to click in one of the disabled checkbox then it would clear, make the selection and then disable the radio? Thanks again!

Comment: @AspClassic-Guy Okay, thanks for the tip. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Now how does that tie into the previous selections?  Slightly confused where to best place that.  Thanks

Comment: I got it, thanks.  In my situation, it might be best to have a button that just clears all selections.  What is best to use for that?  Thank you again.

Comment: @AspClassic-Guy Thank you for your explanation. Hope the latest version will help to fix your issue.

Comment: @Pennny Liu I added a 3rd radio button with the same name and even though the 2 radio buttons work, and works well, the 3rd added radio button doesn't operated the same.  It doesn't gray out the checkboxes.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Found my problem. My 3rd radio had a cap letter in it.  All good thanks to you.

Comment: @AspClassic-Guy Okay, glad you to hear that it works!